# Xamarin project is not showing up on Visual Studio Android Emulator

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-emulator, visual-studio-2019

Its my first time using an Android Emulator. And I have to debug Xamarin-101 project from Microsoft in Visual Studio 2019 but when I click debugging the emulator opening and I can use virtual phone on the emulator but I can't see the Xamarin project on the emulator. Can anyone please give me an idea about it? (I tried to change the virtual device,API and did NuGet Updates)  [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPZoG.png)

Comment: According to the screenshot, the app has not deploied to the device and it is still waiting for the device to be ready. Have you try to test on another enulator or the real device?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean a Shortcut on your Emulators Home Screen?
If yes - Visual Studio does not do that. You can open the list of all installed apps by clicking somewhere in the lower of your emulators screen, holding the left mouse button and swiping upwards.

Apart from that:
If you start a debugging session your app will start automatically. If not, try to stop debugging, press the square on your emulator and whipe a potential running instance of your app. Then, repeat the process of starting your app. Maybe it helps to do a clean rebuild of your project in visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you might be stuck on is the same as what I encountered. Many videos show that when running the emulator for the first time the app auto starts there, but when performing the same on my side I could not get the app on screen to save my life.

In Visual Studio 2019 go to the debug tab and start the app from there, as long as you have the Android emulator set up it should start the emulator and then the app shortly after. Then after that the green play button worked every time from there on.